# Custom UINavigationController: title color

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I need to make a custom navigation controller class for my project, but I'm struggling with navigation bar title color. Bar tint color and tint color are changing properly, but I can't change color of title. Here's my code:

```
    class SANavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        setupAppearance()
        setupBehaviour()
    }

    // MARK: - Setup

    func setupAppearance() {
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
        navigationBar.tintColor = .red
        navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

    private func setupBehaviour() {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change text color of large title you should use

```
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
```

Although it's a bit strange to have same color for text color and `barTintColor` it won't be visible.

Comment: Does titleTextAttributes change both the large and normal title or only the normal title?

Comment: @LloydKeijzer It seems that it only changes normal title attributes. Large title have different attributes.

Comment: @NajdanTomić Thank you, it works. What do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @Lachtan glad it works. I mean if you have same color for text and for barTintColor that text won’t be visible.

Comment: @NajdanTomić Aha, I see. It's just test code:) Good eye!